# How can I use SQL Server Authentication for SSIS Packages Deployment using a Catalog?

Tags: ssis

I'm having a problem while deploying SSIS Package in Integration Services Catalog. It gives me error like this when I try to create a folder in SSISDB

> "Operation 'Create' on object 'CatalogFolder[@Name=SSISTEST']' failed
>   during execution. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc)
>
> For help, click:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=11.0.5058.0+((SQL11_PCU_Main).140514-1820+)&LinkId=20476
>
> ------------------------------ ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or
>   batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
>
> The operation cannot be started by an account that uses SQL Server
>   Authentication. Start the operation with an account that uses Windows
>   Authentication. The operation cannot be started by an account that
>   uses SQL Server Authentication. Start the operation with an account
>   that uses Windows Authentication. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error:
>   27123)"

It seems like I cannot use SQL server authentication user for creating a catalog. When I was trying to Deploy the project through BIDS the same thing happens it's going to use windows authentication which is not valid in my case.

Is there any way I can use SQL server authentication for deployment purpose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SQL Server Authentication is not supported for the Project Deployment model.

There is no hack, no workaround - a windows account must be authenticated to SQL Server and authorized to do the deploy.